# Calculated variable in a sub-query

Tags: sql, subquery, sas, proc-sql

I've got a question for the PROC SQL experts. I have this code:

```
    proc sql;
    create table FinalData as 
    select * 
            ,Sum(starting_year,year_diff) as colsum
            ,Price*(1+(SELECT Return from OtherData where Year=calculated colsum)) as PriceFinal
   from MainData;
   quit;
```

Obviously the `calculated` keyword does not work, I think variables have to be on the same select for that. I want to be able to calculate and use `colsum` in the subquery all within one sql statement. I want to avoid recalculating `colsum` in every subquery because eventually i'll use more complex functions that could slow down the code if recalculated each time.

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487587/use-calculated-values-from-subquery-in-another-variable) which seems to be pretty much the same, but I didn't manage to make the code work with that answer.

EDIT: Changed the code a bit.

It was actually meant to be `Year=calculated colsum`. OtherData is basically a reference table, where `Year` doesn't have duplicates. Here is an example:

```
           MainData                     OtherData
  [Price] [starting_year] [year_diff]         [Return] [Year]
    5.00         2010          5                 0.04    2015
    2.33         2013          3                 0.02    2016
    4.51         2011          1                 0.005   2017
                                                 0.1     2018
```

There will be missing values and thats fine. I know this can be easily done with multiple proc sql statements but the challenge is to do it in a single one. The `SUM` could be any other function that generates an output to be looked up in OtherData.

Is there  a way to do this ?

Comment: . . What are you really trying to do?  It seems that the subquery is going to return more than one row in some cases, and that often generates an error.

Comment: Feels to me like in TSQL/etc. you'd normally run this as a WITH clause/query/whatever, but SAS doesn't have that unfortunately.

Comment: If you give more information about what maindata and otherdata look like, maybe someone can suggest a better approach

Comment: I've added an example and edited for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: Ah.  FCMP isn't very good in 9.2; in 9.3 and (hopefully) 9.4 it's better.

Answer (score 2):

One partial solution to the particular problem is to define your functions as functions.  SQL may be smart enough to not recalculate the same thing twice, although of course with SQL you never know - but it's worth a shot.  At least with the compiled function you gain some efficiency and a bit more of a pointer to SQL to do it properly.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.test;
function bmi(weight,height);
return (weight/height**2);
endsub;
quit;
options cmplib=work.funcs;
proc sql;
select bmi(weight,height) as bmi,
        (select count(1) from sashelp.class S where bmi(s.weight,s.height) le bmi(c.weight,c.height)) as less
    from sashelp.class C;
    quit;
```

You could also create a view with the calculated variable and use that:

```
proc sql;
create view temp as select *, bmi(weight,height) as bmi from sashelp.class;
create table mytable as select C.*, (select count(1) from sashelp.class S where bmi(s.weight,s.height) le C.bmi) from temp C;
quit;
```

Comment: The plot twist is that I'm already using fcmp and unfortunately the values are recalculated each time. Worse yet, fcmp does not play well with sql and sometimes crashes my session while recalculating. I have no idea what a view is but I'll try it. Thanks !

Comment: A view is effectively the instructions to create a table without actually creating it.  It can be accessed identically (mostly) to a table, though, which is convenient for this sort of thing.